# "They asked if I would take..." vs. "they asked if I would have taken..."

Tags: grammar, difference, conditionals

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> I was on a job interiew yesterday and **they asked me if I would take on** more responsibiity if I was asked to.
>
> I was on a job interiew yesterday and **they asked me if I would have taken on** more responsibiity if I had been asked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is what you would normally expect in a job interview, it is a question about a choice you would make if a certain situation occurred, in case the job were offered to you at that company.

> Would you take on more responsibility if you were asked to?

Your second sentence could be pronounced in the case they already decided not to give you the job.

> If you had gotten the job, would you have taken on more responsibility if you had been asked to?

However, it is not clear from the context if the job interviewer speaks about responsibilities offered by that particular employing company, or if it refers to another company for which the applicant worked previously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wanted to say that I was asking about agreeing tenses and the difference in meaning. I'm well aware when to use conditionals, but when it comes to tense ageeing I can't really see the difference. So what's the difference between "they asked me if I would take on more responsibility" and "they asked me if I would have taken more responsibility if I had been asked to"? There is "they asked" and it's in the past. So I'm interested which conditional I use with it and if both possible, what the difference is.

Comment: Both are correct, but they mean different things which I have indicated in my answer.  "they asked me if I would have taken more responsibility if I had been asked to" - it means that you will not be asked to take more responsibilities, whereas in  "they asked me if I would take on more responsibility", there is still a possibility that this may actually happen.

Comment: The second one looks like a question about your previous job.